# using gpuR (how to properly install OpenCL) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, opencl

I have been attempting to install the `gpuR` package as it is a dependency for another package I want to use. However, simply running `install.packages('gpuR')` generates an error. For context, I am using a very new install of Linux. The error:

```
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'gpuR', details:
  call: initContexts()
  error: ViennaCL: FATAL ERROR: ViennaCL encountered an unknown OpenCL error. Most likely your OpenCL SDK or driver is not installed properly. In some cases, this error is due to an invalid global work size or several kernel compilation errors.
```

So it says the potential error clearly there. However, the question now lies on how to properly install OpenCL. Using an AskUbuntu post, I ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ocl-icd-opencl-dev
```

Still, this gave the same error. I browsed the intel forums a bit, and installation seems to vary. What would be the correct steps to install OpenCL so that `gpuR` may be used on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ocl-icd is only the *loader* library. You need to install an *implementation* (that can be loaded by ocl-icd). Where can you get the implementation, depends on what hardware (GPU) you have. I'll assume Intel since you mention their forums. If you have Haswell or older, google for "intel beignet". If you have Broadwell & newer, google "intel compute runtime".